# Which Wacom tablet would suit my needs, Intuos vs. Bamboo?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, drawing-tablet, painting, digital

I am not a graphic design student but digital painiting intrigues me quite a lot. I have been watching online lessons of it and have finally decided to buy a pen tablet. I want to pursue digital painiting as a hobby.

Budget is not a constraint for me (owing to the hige price difference between Bamboo and Intuous) but I want to use the money effectively.

Which tablet would you suggest me to buy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My first piece of advice is to be sure of the size you need. I have the Intuos A3, but I end up using only a section of the available surface. When I used the whole surface I found the increased travel was actually giving me RSI in the elbow. The size smaller would have been sufficient for my needs in the end. Perhaps you can rent one to try out?

I regularly use both - the larger Intuos at my studio and the lighter Bamboo  for when I'm working offsite - and I'd say you can feel the difference in the build quality; the Intuos pen and tablet itself feel nice and solid, while the Bamboo feels a little bit light and flimsy, but not by much. While there is technically a difference in the pressure sensitivity of both models if I were to be honest *I* don't notice the difference much. However, if you're going to use it for painting you might well need that extra degree of sensitivity.

Finally be aware that if you've never used a tablet before it feels *really* weird at first, so don't be disheartened. It took me a week or so to get really comfortable with one and now I can't live without it!

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think I have any option to try out. I am going for the smallest size for now, but I am not able to decide which model to buy. Would you recommend any other company than Wacom?

Comment: If budget is not an issue and you're definitely going to use the tablet a lot then I'd advise you get the Intuos if only for the more solid build quality. Having said that, the Bamboo is still an excellent tablet, especially for a first purchase or if you're not sure if you're going to like using a tablet.

Comment: I've only ever used Wacom tablets, so I can't vouch for any other manufacturer. Don't forgot depending on where you buy it from you'll probably get some kind of money back guarantee, so you could try it out for a while at least.